# Add a table column into my cart list instead of row

Tags: php, laravel

On my website, I have a users table and industry table and industry_overview table. industry_overview contain the overview data of an industry.

I want to have a "Add to Cart" function where user can add the overview detail such as value chain, market share and market price into their cart list.(Cart list item will eventually be merged and generate a report out in pdf form)

May I know what is the simplest way I could get something like that done? I've thought about this but I can't seem to find a solution or idea.

I don't need a ready-made script, just any idea that could get me working then will be great! (Also if you already have an example of such function, I'd be more than happy to have a look at it).

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Industry overview table has 5 column:
overview_id
industry_id
value_chain
market_share
market_price

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you would like to add new columns to a table based on the input of a user into the industry_overview table? And then add a row of data?

Comment: @party-ring nope, i want to add a record into cart table. This record will tell me which user created this record, and what are the content the user added to cart (exp: value chain/ market share)

Comment: @party-ring As the overview table has 3 information of the industry (market share, market price and value chain), i can select only one of them to add into my cart. But i dont know how to save this record and the way to identify which column i added into my cart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using `carts` and `cart_items` tables:

```
carts
=====
- id
- user_id

cart_items
==========
- id
- cart_id
- industry_overview_id
- column
```

If you want a user to have multiple simultaneous carts you can add a `name` column, which the user can change.

Any data point (column in `industry_overview`) selected by the user will result in an entry in the `cart_items` table.

However, with this method a user's cart items will automatically be "updated" if the value of the overview item changes. If you don't want this you could save the exact values from `industry_overview` into the `cart_items` table, either instead of or in addition to the id.

Comment: If I have one more table called industry_background, which contain history_roadmap and flow_chart columns, can this two tables be apply also? Or do I need to add one more column(named "section") to cart_items and change the "industry_overview_id" into "section_id"

Comment: Yes, or you could use a [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) on cart_items.